# Removing fluctuations in plot, possibly due to numerical precision

Tags: plotting, numerics

Through the following code, we generate Tp1:

```
tempPV = (
  3 π^(2/3) + 6 6^(2/3) P π V^(2/3) - 
   6^(2/3) V^(
    2/3) (-3 + Sqrt[
      9 + (4 6^(2/3) π^(4/3) q^2)/(
       V^(4/3) β^2)]) β^2 + 
   3 6^(2/3) V^(
    2/3) β^2 Log[
     1/6 (3 + Sqrt[
        9 + (4 6^(2/3) π^(4/3) q^2)/(V^(4/3) β^2)])])/(
  6 6^(1/3) π^(4/3) V^(1/3));

βin = 0.01;
βfi = 100;
βst = 0.005;
Table[
  xlog[β] = Log[10, β]
  , {β, βin, βfi, βst}];

parap1 = {q -> 0.1, V4 -> 5000};
parap2 = {T2 -> 15, q -> 0.1, V2 -> 10000};
parap4 = {T4 -> 5, q -> 0.1, V4 -> 5000};

Table[
  pressp2[β] = 
   P /. Solve[(tempPV - T2 == 0) /. V -> V2 /. parap2, P][[1]];(*p1=
  p2*)
  pressp4[β] = 
   P /. Solve[(tempPV - T4 == 0) /. V -> V4 /. parap4, P][[1]];(*p3=
  p4*)
  Tp1[β] = 
   T1 /. Solve[(tempPV - T1 == 0) /. V -> V4 /. parap1 /. 
       P -> pressp2[β], T1][[1]];
  , {β, βin, βfi, βst}];

mi = Min[Table[Tp1[β], {β, βin, βfi, βst}]]
ma = Max[Table[Tp1[β], {β, βin, βfi, βst}]]

ListPlot[
 Table[{xlog[β], Tp1[β]}, {β, βin, βfi, βst}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Rescale[#, {mi, ma}, {0.`, 1.`}] &, 
   Rescale[#, {0.`, 1.`}, {mi, ma}] &}, Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, PrintPrecision -> 11}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(10\)]\) (β)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(1\)]\)"}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {mi, ma}}, Axes -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
 ImageSize -> 400, FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

The result is the following plot:

[image: plot with fuzzy tail]

There is a strange fluctuation for $log_{10}^{\beta}=1-2$. As it should be a smoothly decreasing function, what is the origin of these fluctuations? How to fix this possibly numerical error?

Comment: You should really consider radically refactoring your code to take advantage of vectorized operations. First of all, remove all the `[beta]` indices and do not iterate over the values of beta. For instance, `Table[xlog[β] = Log[10, β], {β, βin, βfi, βst}];` should really just be `xlog = Log10@Range[βin, βfi, βst];`. Second, pre-calculate the symbolic solution of the `Solve` equations in your table ONLY ONCE and then plug in values of beta to get your vectors of results. This will save A LOT of time.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes you are right. This saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more idiomatic approach:

```
para = {q -> 1/10, V4 -> 5000, T2 -> 15, V2 -> 10000, T4 -> 5};
Psol = First@Solve[tempPV - T2 == 0 /. V -> V2 /. para, P];
T1sol = T1 /. First@Solve[tempPV - T1 == 0 /. V -> V4 /. para, T1] /. Psol;

Block[
  {tmin = T1sol /. β -> βfi, tmax = T1sol /. β -> βin},
  LogLinearPlot[
    (T1sol - tmin)/(tmax - tmin), {β, βin, βfi},
    PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 20,
    Axes -> False, Frame -> True
  ]
]
```

[image: plot from LogLinear plot, appropriately scaled]

---

Here is a completely refactored version of your code that runs quite a bit faster even though the calculations are carried out at much higher arbitrary precision:

```
(* Re-defined these as arbitrary-precision numbers rather than machine-precision reals *)
βin = 1/100; βfi = 100; βst = 5/1000;

(* Vectorize and avoid Table *)
xlog = Log10@Range[βin, βfi, βst];

(* grouped all parameters together so you only have one location to change *)
(* also re-defined the values as arbitrary-precision numbers               *)
para = {q -> 1/10, V4 -> 5000, T2 -> 15, V2 -> 10000, T4 -> 5};

(* Solve all equations ONLY ONCE, then plug in values when needed          *)
pressp2 = P /. First@Solve[(tempPV - T2 == 0) /. V -> V2 /. para, P];
Tp1 = T1 /. First@Solve[(tempPV - T1 == 0) /. V -> V4 /. para, T1] /. P -> pressp2;

(* Plug in the values of beta *)
(* Using 20-digit arbitrary-precision numerical values; fewer digits still gives artifacts *)
Tp1values = Tp1 /. β -> N[Range[βin, βfi, βst], 20];

(* Rescale values of Tp1 to run between 0 and 1                       *)
(* Pair the rescaled values with the corresponding abscissa from xlog *)
rescaledPaired = Transpose@{xlog, Rescale[Tp1values]};

(* Generate plot *)
ListLinePlot[
  rescaledPaired,
  PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05],
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: expected plot of a monotonically decreasing function, without the fuzzy tail]

---

Note that `pressp4` was never needed to generate your plot, so I removed it from above. Nevertheless it would be obtained as follows:

```
pressp4 = P /. First@Solve[(tempPV - T4 == 0) /. V -> V4 /. para, P];
```

Comment: @MacroB Wow! How a nice code. I learnt a lot from it. Thanks a lot for your time and consideration. You helped me a lot.